# How to retrieve certain data from URL in Angular 2.0

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a URL like this one:

`https://example.com/?username1=Dr&Organization=Pepper&action=create`

I need to display it on my browser inside a text box.

```
<input type="text" name="varname" value="Dr">
```

I need to get `Dr` in my textbox

Comment: `<input type="text" name="varname" value="https://example.com/?username1=Dr&Organization=Pepper&action=create">`?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: We are using Angular 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm presuming your url endpoint returns JSON and your attempting to use the returned data to populate your input value.*

Firstly import the HttpClientModule in your module dependencies:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then from within your `foo.component.ts` you can inject an instance of HttpClient in the constructor.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient){
  }
```

Then you can use said `HttpClient` instance `http` like so:

```
this.http.get('https://example.com/?username1=Dr&Organization=Pepper&action=create').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

This can then be put into a property (`myProp`) which can be referenced like so:

```
<input *ngIf="myProp" type="text" name="varname" value="myProp">
```

Note that we use `*ngIF` to make sure that our property isn't loaded until `myProp` is not `null` or `undefined`.

---

Main App component - app-root

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  name = null;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient){
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('https://example.com/?username1=Dr&Organization=Pepper&action=create').subscribe(data => {
    // data = result: {name: 'Derek da Doctor'}
      this.name = data.result.name;
    });
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<input *ngIf="name" type="text" name="varname" value="{{name}}">
```